# Substituir multiiplas palavras por uma

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria de substituir multiplas palavras por uma apenas
por exemplo:

Isto foi o que eu tentei, aqui apenas a primeira ocorrência é alterada

```
var replaceGN = "Gênesis"
var str = "Este é o livro de GEN, Gn é o primeiro livro da bíblia, leia Gen.";
var matchesGN = str.match( /GN|GEN|GEN\./g );
r = str.replace(/[matchesGN]/g, replaceGN)
alert(r);
```

> dado um índice

```
1-GE
1-GEN
1-GEN.
1-GÊN
1-GENESIS
1-GÊNESIS
1-GÉNESIS
1-GN
1-GN.
2-OUTRO
2-OUT
2-OUT.
2-OU.
```

> dado valor de cada índice

```
1=Gênesis
2=Outro
```

> String

"Este é o livro de Genesis, Gn é o primeiro livro da bíblia
Este é Out. livro, Ou. livro interessante"

> Resultado esperado

"Este é o livro de Gênesis, Gênesis é o primeiro livro da bíblia
Este é Outro livro, Outro livro interessante"

Comment: @AugustoVasques coloquei o que eu vinha tentando sem sucesso.

Comment: `"Este é o livro de GEN, Gn é o primeiro livro da bíblia, leia Gen.".replace(/\b(GN|GEN)\b/ig, "Gênesis")`

Comment: Uau, muito simples e eficiente, Obrigado @ValdeirPsr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É só adaptar

```
var NovoValor = "Gênesis";
var Texto = "Este é o livro de GEN, Gn é o primeiro livro da bíblia, leia Gen.";
var ListaPalavras = ["GEN", "GN", "Gen", "Gn"];

for(index in ListaPalavras) {
   Texto = Texto.replace(ListaPalavras[index], NovoValor);
}

alert(Texto);
```

Comment: Perfeito @Allan, Muito Obrigado!